# How do I stop a thread in an eclipse Job?

Tags: multithreading, eclipse-plugin

I really need the help of the kind wizards on this site. I created a job in the `execute()` of my `AbstractHandler`. The job has a progress monitor and everything works fine until I try to abort the job.

When a user clicks on the cancel button, the progress monitor screen goes off but a thread started within the job continues to run in the background. Calling `cancel()` on the job does not stop the child thread. Calling `interrupt()` does nothing either.

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {


    ...
    job = new Job("Doing my job") {

        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            monitor.beginTask("Running a length thread",10);
            monitor.worked(1);
            Thread unstoppableThread; //the pain in my neck


                    try {
                        unstoppableThread = new Thread() {
                            public void run() {

                                //A lengthy process
                            }

                        };

                    int i = 1;
                    while(unstoppableThread.isAlive()){

                        if(monitor.isCanceled()){
                            //job.cancel(); doesn't work
                            //IJobManager manager = Job.getJobManager();
                            //manager.cancel(job); doesn't work
                            //unstoppableThread.interrupt(); doesn't work too
                            return Status.CANCEL_STATUS; 
                        }

                        try {
                            if(i<8)monitor.worked(1);
                            i++;
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }


            }finally{
               monitor.done(); 
            }

            return Status.OK_STATUS; 
        }                                        //end of Job#run()

    };                                           //end of Job block

    job.setUser(true);
    job.schedule();
    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the "unstoppable thread" to cooperate; it needs to periodically check its own interrupt flag, and stop when it becomes true. Then in your "cancel" code, call `unstoppableThread.interrupt()`, and it will actually work.

In other words, the `run()` method of your unstoppable thread needs to look like

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        // Do a little work
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a better pattern to use `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` so you don't clear the flag.  Doesn't matter in this case but for others...

Comment: @Ernest, thanks for your response, unfortunately for me, the thread cannot be processed in little chunks of work. There are call to third party tools in the `run()` method     {public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        // a lengthy task; I need a break!
    }
}}

Comment: As a last resort, there's always `Thread.stop()`. Once in a while, that's the only alternative you have; this might be one of those cases.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using a discouraged method. Oh well! It works! ...I hope I wont suffer the consequences in the future.